# How resolve my EXC_BAD_ACCESS (SIGSEGV)

Tags: ios, objective-c, crash-reports

I run my application on iOS 8.2.
The application is runing and execute my code well,
on one of my tested devices it is crashed.
how can i fix it? why it is crash on specific device?

I run a zombie test, there is no zombies.

Here is my report :

**The report**

```
Incident Identifier: 2FE49173-1095-4C3A-9C62-90DE42E2C36C
CrashReporter Key:   5eef5ed6836a516df28edf43fa49acb835c19cfc
Hardware Model:      iPhone4,1
Process:             LEAF_v2 [134]
Path:                /private/var/mobile/Containers/Bundle/Application/026ED771-7A19-486E-85D2-4CDEABD31DCA/LEAF_v2.app/LEAF_v2
Identifier:          com.SDS.LEAF-v2
Version:             1.0.150322 (1.0)
Code Type:           ARM (Native)
Parent Process:      launchd [1]

Date/Time:           2015-03-23 08:09:50.079 +0200
Launch Time:         2015-03-23 07:48:37.407 +0200
OS Version:          iOS 8.2 (12D508)
Report Version:      105

Exception Type:  EXC_BAD_ACCESS (SIGSEGV)
Exception Subtype: KERN_INVALID_ADDRESS at 0x496ae690
Triggered by Thread:  6

Thread 0 name:  Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread
Thread 0:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x3a81449c 0x3a813000 + 5276
1   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x3a814290 0x3a813000 + 4752
2   CoreFoundation                  0x2c4607f6 0x2c392000 + 845814
3   CoreFoundation                  0x2c45edbc 0x2c392000 + 839100
4   CoreFoundation                  0x2c3abb4c 0x2c392000 + 105292
5   CoreFoundation                  0x2c3ab95e 0x2c392000 + 104798
6   GraphicsServices                0x339111a4 0x33908000 + 37284
7   UIKit                           0x2f9fdc8c 0x2f98f000 + 453772
8   LEAF_v2                         0x0009b1dc 0x93000 + 33244
9   libdyld.dylib                   0x3a761aac 0x3a760000 + 6828

Thread 1 name:  Dispatch queue: com.apple.libdispatch-manager
Thread 1:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x3a81424c 0x3a813000 + 4684
1   libdispatch.dylib               0x3a7344ec 0x3a722000 + 74988
2   libdispatch.dylib               0x3a73421e 0x3a722000 + 74270

Thread 2 name:  com.apple.coremedia.player.async
Thread 2:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x3a8144ec 0x3a813000 + 5356
1   libdispatch.dylib               0x3a731b8e 0x3a722000 + 64398
2   MediaToolbox                    0x2deb1b56 0x2dead000 + 19286
3   CoreMedia                       0x2cc07bb4 0x2cbd9000 + 191412
4   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x3a8a6de8 0x3a8a4000 + 11752
5   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x3a8a6d5a 0x3a8a4000 + 11610
6   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x3a8a4b04 0x3a8a4000 + 2820

Thread 3 name:  com.apple.NSURLConnectionLoader
Thread 3:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x3a81449c 0x3a813000 + 5276
1   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x3a814290 0x3a813000 + 4752
2   CoreFoundation                  0x2c4607f6 0x2c392000 + 845814
3   CoreFoundation                  0x2c45edbc 0x2c392000 + 839100
4   CoreFoundation                  0x2c3abb4c 0x2c392000 + 105292
5   CoreFoundation                  0x2c3ab95e 0x2c392000 + 104798
6   CFNetwork                       0x2bf5f722 0x2bee3000 + 509730
7   Foundation                      0x2d1d44b6 0x2d103000 + 857270
8   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x3a8a6de8 0x3a8a4000 + 11752
9   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x3a8a6d5a 0x3a8a4000 + 11610
10  libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x3a8a4b04 0x3a8a4000 + 2820

Thread 4 name:  com.apple.CFSocket.private
Thread 4:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x3a828080 0x3a813000 + 86144
1   CoreFoundation                  0x2c464f7e 0x2c392000 + 864126
2   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x3a8a6de8 0x3a8a4000 + 11752
3   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x3a8a6d5a 0x3a8a4000 + 11610
4   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x3a8a4b04 0x3a8a4000 + 2820

Thread 5:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x3a81449c 0x3a813000 + 5276
1   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x3a814290 0x3a813000 + 4752
2   CoreFoundation                  0x2c4607f6 0x2c392000 + 845814
3   CoreFoundation                  0x2c45edbc 0x2c392000 + 839100
4   CoreFoundation                  0x2c3abb4c 0x2c392000 + 105292
5   CoreFoundation                  0x2c3f5546 0x2c392000 + 406854
6   CoreMotion                      0x2ccba3c6 0x2cc75000 + 283590
7   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x3a8a6de8 0x3a8a4000 + 11752
8   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x3a8a6d5a 0x3a8a4000 + 11610
9   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x3a8a4b04 0x3a8a4000 + 2820

Thread 6 name:  Dispatch queue: com.apple.root.default-qos
Thread 6 Crashed:
0   libsqlite3.dylib                0x3a4c2914 0x3a4a2000 + 133396
1   libsqlite3.dylib                0x3a4ae31a 0x3a4a2000 + 49946
2   libsqlite3.dylib                0x3a4ac08a 0x3a4a2000 + 41098
3   libsqlite3.dylib                0x3a4ab866 0x3a4a2000 + 39014
4   libsqlite3.dylib                0x3a4ab256 0x3a4a2000 + 37462
5   libsqlite3.dylib                0x3a4aafc6 0x3a4a2000 + 36806
6   libsqlite3.dylib                0x3a4ecf24 0x3a4a2000 + 306980
7   LEAF_v2                         0x000d5404 0x93000 + 271364
8   LEAF_v2                         0x000f61a0 0x93000 + 405920
9   libdispatch.dylib               0x3a723c80 0x3a722000 + 7296
10  libdispatch.dylib               0x3a730866 0x3a722000 + 59494
11  libdispatch.dylib               0x3a73189e 0x3a722000 + 63646
12  libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x3a8a4da6 0x3a8a4000 + 3494
13  libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x3a8a4af8 0x3a8a4000 + 2808

Thread 7:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x3a8289c0 0x3a813000 + 88512
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x3a8a4e20 0x3a8a4000 + 3616
2   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x3a8a4af8 0x3a8a4000 + 2808

Thread 8 name:  Dispatch queue: com.apple.root.default-qos
Thread 8:
0   libsystem_malloc.dylib          0x3a851a5a 0x3a84f000 + 10842
1   libsqlite3.dylib                0x3a4bcf44 0x3a4a2000 + 110404
2   libsqlite3.dylib                0x3a52bd38 0x3a4a2000 + 564536
3   libsqlite3.dylib                0x3a4ba98a 0x3a4a2000 + 100746
4   libsqlite3.dylib                0x3a4c7272 0x3a4a2000 + 152178
5   libsqlite3.dylib                0x3a4c6ce6 0x3a4a2000 + 150758
6   libsqlite3.dylib                0x3a534082 0x3a4a2000 + 598146
7   libsqlite3.dylib                0x3a4c2fcc 0x3a4a2000 + 135116
8   libsqlite3.dylib                0x3a4acfbe 0x3a4a2000 + 44990
9   libsqlite3.dylib                0x3a4ac08a 0x3a4a2000 + 41098
10  libsqlite3.dylib                0x3a4ab8da 0x3a4a2000 + 39130
11  libsqlite3.dylib                0x3a4ab256 0x3a4a2000 + 37462
12  libsqlite3.dylib                0x3a4aafc6 0x3a4a2000 + 36806
13  libsqlite3.dylib                0x3a4ecf24 0x3a4a2000 + 306980
14  LEAF_v2                         0x000d4fa6 0x93000 + 270246
15  LEAF_v2                         0x000f61a0 0x93000 + 405920
16  libdispatch.dylib               0x3a723c80 0x3a722000 + 7296
17  libdispatch.dylib               0x3a730866 0x3a722000 + 59494
18  libdispatch.dylib               0x3a73189e 0x3a722000 + 63646
19  libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x3a8a4da6 0x3a8a4000 + 3494
20  libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x3a8a4af8 0x3a8a4000 + 2808

Thread 9:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x3a8289c0 0x3a813000 + 88512
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x3a8a4e20 0x3a8a4000 + 3616
2   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x3a8a4af8 0x3a8a4000 + 2808

Thread 10:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x3a8289c0 0x3a813000 + 88512
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x3a8a4e20 0x3a8a4000 + 3616
2   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x3a8a4af8 0x3a8a4000 + 2808

Thread 6 crashed with ARM Thread State (32-bit):
    r0: 0x91825aa4    r1: 0x03617c00      r2: 0x496ae690      r3: 0x00000000
    r4: 0x1557fe00    r5: 0x03617b80      r6: 0x155b4600      r7: 0x00b4ba48
    r8: 0x03617700    r9: 0x000000ed     r10: 0x00000000     r11: 0x00000000
    ip: 0x00000000    sp: 0x00b4ba38      lr: 0x3a4ae31f      pc: 0x3a4c2914
  cpsr: 0x00000030
```

Comment: Look up instructions for symbolicating the crash to make it more useful.  It looks like your problem is in a call to the sqlite3 library.  Getting proper symbols for "14  LEAF_v2 0x000d4fa6 0x93000 + 270246
15  LEAF_v2 0x000f61a0 0x93000 + 405920" may help.

Comment: I am not understand what to do? there is a file where to look?
I see that only thread 6 crash? how you know that it is sql?

Comment: "Thread 6 Crashed:
0   libsqlite3.dylib                0x3a4c2914 0x3a4a2000 + 133396"

Comment: ok, i see and how i know where it is in the code? or how to fix it?
Can you please help me?

Comment: Look here for instructions on symbolicating a crash so that you can find where it happened in the code: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1460892/symbolicating-iphone-app-crash-reports